# Unable to run Gatsby application using npm run develop command

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I am developing my first project with Gatsby and prismic. Today when i tried to start my development server i faced this error. I searched but i couldn't find similar errors anywhere. I am completely blocked on this one and have no clue what's causing this error.

**extract from package.json :**

```
"scripts": {
    "build-dev": "env-cmd -f .env gatsby build",
    "develop-dev": "env-cmd -f .env gatsby develop",
      ....
  },
```

**The error**

```
ERROR 

UNHANDLED REJECTION Union type PrismicAllDocumentTypes must define one or more member types.



  Error: Union type PrismicAllDocumentTypes must define one or more member types.

  - query-compiler.js:202 extractOperations
    [site]/[gatsby]/dist/query/query-compiler.js:202:20

  - query-compiler.js:176 processQueries
    [site]/[gatsby]/dist/query/query-compiler.js:176:7

  - query-compiler.js:96 compile
    [vav_site]/[gatsby]/dist/query/query-compiler.js:96:19

  - index.js:484 async module.exports
    [site]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:484:3

  - develop.js:446 async module.exports
    [site]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/develop.js:446:7


not finished extract queries from components - 0.675s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop-dev: `env-cmd -f .env gatsby develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop-dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Internal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-10T07_36_38_243Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

gatsby version : 2.19.34
react version : 16.13.0
prismic-reactjs version :1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed `npm install -g gatsby-cli`.

[Update] Prismic is not longer recommending the `gatsby-source-prismic-graphql` plugin.

Here's an article that'll help you migrating to the other one:

[How to migrate a project from 'gatsby-source-prismic' to 'gatsby-source-prismic-graphql'](https://user-guides.prismic.io/en/articles/4534769-how-to-migrate-a-project-from-gatsby-source-prismic-graphql-to-gatsby-source-prismic)

Answer (score 1):

Error says that PrismicAllDocumentTypes has no children. You need to check that your prismic repo has at least one content type and, most important, you have at least one schema added to your codebase and gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-prismic`,
      options: {
        repositoryName: `repositoryName`,
        accessToken: `accessToken`,
        linkResolver: ({ node, key, value }) => post => `/${post.uid}`,
        schemas: {
          page: require("./src/schemas/page.json"),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using my own prismic source gatsby package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-VARIABLE-prismic",
  "description": "YOUR DESCRIPTION",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "YOURNAME <YOUR@EMAIL.ADDRESS> (@USERNAME)",
 "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "dev": "gatsby develop -o",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:ci": "yarn lint --format junit -o results/eslint/result.xml",
    "format": "prettier \"**/*.md \" --write",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:run:ci": "cypress run --browser chrome --reporter junit --reporter-options 'mochaFile=results/cypress/result.xml'",
    "test:e2e:dev": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y start-server-and-test dev http://localhost:8000 cy:open",
    "test:e2e:run": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y start-server-and-test develop http://localhost:8000 cy:run",
    "test:e2e:ci": "cross-env CYPRESS_SUPPORT=y start-server-and-test develop http://localhost:8000 cy:run:ci"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.28",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
    "@emotion/styled-base": "^10.0.28",
    "@reach/skip-nav": "^0.8.5",
    "emotion": "^10.0.27",
    "emotion-server": "^10.0.27",
    "emotion-theming": "^10.0.27",
    "gatsby": "^2.19.23",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.41",
    "gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^4.1.22",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.1.36",
    "gatsby-plugin-lodash": "^3.1.20",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.42",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.1.33",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.35",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.22",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.4.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.27",
    "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^2.3.22",
    "gatsby-source-prismic": "^2.2.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.16",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "prismic-dom": "^2.1.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.19.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-typography": "^0.16.19",
    "typeface-lora": "^0.0.72",
    "typeface-source-sans-pro": "^1.1.5",
    "typography": "^0.16.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "cypress": "^3.8.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-cypress": "^0.2.22",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.10.9"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby",
    "starter",
    "prismic",
    "typography",
    "minimal",
    "gatsby-starter"
  ]
}
```

in your gatsby-condig.js:

```
 resolve: 'gatsby-source-prismic',
      options: {
        repositoryName: 'gatsby-starter-prismic',
        accessToken: `${process.env.API_KEY}`,
        // Get the correct URLs in blog posts
        linkResolver: () => post => `/${post.uid}`,
        // PrismJS highlighting for labels and slices
        htmlSerializer: () => prismicHtmlSerializer,
        // Remove this config option if you only have one language in your Prismic repository
        lang: 'en-gb',
      },
    },
```

you are probbly using .dotenv - a way to pass secret keys outside of publc ic repo's.

in your root directory create a file named " .env.develop "  and a second: ".env.prod "

.env.develop file content:
`API_KEY = COPYPASE YOUR API KEY HERE`